# object.count returns 0. But object.any? returns true. What's happening?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

`@card.submissions` returns this:

```
<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Submission id: nil, user_id: nil, card_id: 7, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, text: "">]>
```

`@card.submissions.any?` returns `true`.

`@card.submissions.count` returns `0`.

What I'm looking to implement is:

```
if @card.submissions.any?
  render @card.submissions
end
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looks like Submission is a new record (since id is nil). If it's new, it hasn't made it to the database yet.  `count` makes a SQL call to the database to determine the number of rows so is rightly returning zero.   `any?` is returning true since there is an object in the collection.

What happens if you try `@card.submissions.to_a.size` (to ensure you load them from the database then check the size of the array).

Comment: This is right, today I learned something. For reference, here's the [`count`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-count) method, and the [`any?`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-any-3F) methods.

Comment: Phillip you're right. That returns 1. I have a form for a submission (and I'm initializing it with Submission.new) on that same page. How could I go about solving this? (without using @card.submission.count... which I see as inelegant)

Comment: `@card.submissions.size` would be enough - relation does not define size method so it will delegate it to target. BTW - using `size` instead of `count` is a good way to get rid of N+1 problem.

Comment: @BroiSatse Not always. Sometimes it makes a SQL call. ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy.size says: Returns the size of the collection. If the collection hasn't been loaded, it executes a SELECT COUNT(*) query. Else it calls collection.size.

Comment: @alejoriveralara Solve what exactly? Not sure I know what your end goal is (new vs persisted records, etc.)?

Comment: @PhilipHallstrom nevermind! To avoid using count but still initialize that new submission. However, I ended up using ```count```. Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 0):

An old question, but I would like to chip in nonetheless. I came across a similar issue, and found:

```
@card.submissions.any? = true
@card.submissions.count = 0
```

even though there were no records in my database, but I had initialised an empty `@card.submission` object which was in the `@card.submissions` array.

To mitigate this problem, I tried

```
@card.submissions.all.any?
```

which reloaded the array from the database, and returned `false`.